# Download a picture from a blob using python ( azure Blob storage)

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

I want to download an image from a `blob` that is in a container.
I  searched and I only found how to download a container, but as I said I do not want to download the whole container and not the whole `blob` otherwise just an image.
(container/blob/image.png)
this is the code that i found ( to download all the container):

```py
import os
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient
from azure.storage.blob import ContentSettings, ContainerClient
    
# IMPORTANT: Replace connection string with your storage account connection string
# Usually starts with DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;...
MY_CONNECTION_STRING = "CONNECTION_STRING"
# Replace with blob container
MY_BLOB_CONTAINER = "name"
    
# Replace with the local folder where you want files to be downloaded
LOCAL_BLOB_PATH = "Blobsss"
    
BLOBNAME="test"
class AzureBlobFileDownloader:
    def __init__(self):
        print("Intializing AzureBlobFileDownloader")
    
        # Initialize the connection to Azure storage account
        self.blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(MY_CONNECTION_STRING)
        self.my_container = self.blob_service_client.get_container_client(MY_BLOB_CONTAINER)
    
    def save_blob(self, file_name, file_content):
        # Get full path to the file
        download_file_path = os.path.join(LOCAL_BLOB_PATH, file_name)
    
        # for nested blobs, create local path as well!
        os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(download_file_path), exist_ok=True)
    
        with open(download_file_path, "wb") as file:
            file.write(file_content)
    
    
    def download_all_blobs_in_container(self):
        my_blobs = self.my_container.list_blobs()
        for blob in my_blobs:
            print(blob.name)
            bytes = self.my_container.get_blob_client(blob).download_blob().readall()
            self.save_blob(blob.name, bytes)
    
    
# Initialize class and upload files
azure_blob_file_downloader = AzureBlobFileDownloader()
azure_blob_file_downloader.download_all_blobs_in_container()
```

Could you please help me ?
thanks you

Comment: Not sure i understand your question. You mentioned wanting to download `container/blob/image.png` - the thing is, blob storage is `<accountname>.blob.core.windows.net/container/<blob-name>`. So if you wanted to download your image, which is a blob, it would be more like `containername/image.png`. As far as how you do it, your code already does it, except it does it for each blob in a container, in a loop. Have you tried just downloading via the exact same code in that loop, without a loop? tl;dr you should have everything you need, in the code you already shared.